# Unity audio perameters when picked up item?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, fmod

So I'm creating a game in unity and I want the music to change when the player picks up different items eg a coin, bread, etc. But I'm not sure where I would get started with that does anyone have links or knowledge on how I can do this? Also I am using FMOD but don't want to use FMOD to do this

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the component, called Box Collider.

1. Unity->Help->Script Reference, open API documentation.
2. Search: collider, then find a function, named OnTriggerEnter.
3. Then follow the example.

[How to open API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp6wX.jpg)

[Search and find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydRWh.jpg)

[OnTriggerEnter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrNws.jpg)

Comment: This API can help detecting when two gameObjects collide, and then you can use script to do something, such as playing different music.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a script containing this to the `AudioSource` that plays the music.
Make sure that `loop` is unchecked on the `AudioSource`

```
    public AudioClip normalClip;//the music to play normally
    public AudioClip specialClip;//the music to play when an item is obtained
    AudioSource audioSource;//the music player

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();//find the music player on this GameObject
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //if music player finished playing, start next loop of normal music
        if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            audioSource.clip = normalClip;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
    
    //starts a loop of the item-obtained music
    void OnObtainedItem(){
        audioSource.clip = specialClip;
        audioSource.Play();
    }
```

When you collect an item, call `OnObtainedItem();`